# Certificate used for S2S authentication of Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement Onpremise with Exchange Online has expired

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have the following error:

> Certificate used for S2S authentication of Dynamics 365 for Customer
>   Engagement Onpremise with Exchange Online has expired

Has anyone had this error before? Can you give me more clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates are only valid for a period of time, I'm going to guess your certificate has expired due to age.

["Exchange Online Security Certificate Expiration" error message displayed in Dynamics 365 On-premises or Dynamics 365 for Outlook.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/dn946906(v=crm.8)#exchange-online-security-certificate-expiration-error-message-displayed-in-dynamics-365-on-premises-or-dynamics-365-for-outlook)

> **Applies to Microsoft Dynamics 365 Server configured with a connection
> to Exchange Online** or SharePoint Online. The message states "Please
> update your certificate or Exchange Online integration will stop
> functioning in [number] days."
>
> **To resolve this issue, update the x509 digital certificate** issued by a
> trusted certificate authority **used to authenticate between Dynamics
> 365 (on-premises) and Exchange Online** or SharePoint Online.

Looks like you will need to get a valid certificate and repeat the setup process described here [Connect Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement (on-premises) to Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/on-premises/connect-dynamics-365-on-premises-exchange-online)

> #### Verify prerequisites
>
> ...
>
> - An x509 digital certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority that will be used to authenticate between Dynamics 365
>   (on-premises) and Exchange Online. If you are evaluating server-based
>   authentication, you can use a self-signed certificate.

In particular step "5. Set the certificate" here [Configure server-based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/on-premises/connect-dynamics-365-on-premises-exchange-online#configure-server-based-authentication)

```
$STSCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList c:\Personalcertfile.pfx, personal_certfile_password
$PFXCertificateBin = $STSCertificate.GetRawCertData()
$Certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$Certificate.Import(“c:\Personalcertfile.cer”)
$CERCertificateBin = $Certificate.GetRawCertData()
$CredentialValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CERCertificateBin)
```